# Bluetooth crashes from time to time [more below] Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 20.10

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, alsa, headphones, blueman

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 5537, the chip that came with it was not AC compliant, so I replaced it by the Intel Wireless-AC 7260HMW, I knew support has been recently added for this card.

The problem is that bluetooth crashes constantly,my keyboard gets disconnected all the time and my headphones have some issues as well, sometimes the music volume goes down, sometimes it stops, sometimes it stutters...

In order to get the issue solved, I installed blueman manager, alsa mixer and tried to change some configurations on the bluetooth ctl files.

Messed so much it went crazy, then reinstalled Ubuntu again to check if I could get it sorted,  but no luck.

Then I updated to Ubuntu 20.10, maybe that was a huge mistake, but I will probably update to the next LTS version comming anyways.

1. uname -r
   5.8.0-44-generic
2. sudo lshw | grep -i blue
   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
   product: Bluetooth wireless interface
   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
3. sudo lshw | grep -i 7260
   product: Wireless 7260
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-44-generic
   firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode ip=192.168.178.19 latency=0 link=yes
   multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

I know bluetooth is very hot topic on the Linux community due to all the different proprietary standards out there and let me apologize beforehand if I am making the same question as someone else did before, but I swear I tried to solve it by myself first...

I also would like to tell that it's pretty weird that I can't use the tag 7260HMW if my problem does seem to be related to it =S, I wish everyone with the same card could easily find it.

TL;DR: My bluetooth keyboard disconnects from time to time, it doesn't seem to have a typical periodicity. And also the bluetooth headphones stutters or lags a lot. How to solve it?

Comment: So where are you now and what is the question?

Comment: My bluetooth keyboard disconnects from time to time, it doesn't seem to have a typical periodicity. And also the bluetooth headphones stutters or lags a lot. I am in the Netherlands, sorry for the delay, I didn't expect an answer so fast

Comment: I am in Sweden and hang out here quite a bit. Maybe add that comment you just made to the end of your question to sum it up. Sorry I do not have a fix for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David. I added a TL;DR session in the end.

Comment: I'm now having the problem (with the headset) after updating from 20.10 to 21.04. 20.10 had no problems, 21.04 has. Even after a full clean reinstall 21.04 still has the problem.